# What is a better way than a for loop to implement an algorithm that involves sets?

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, set

I'm trying to create an algorithm along these lines:

-Create 8 participants

-Each participant has a set of interests

-Pair them with another participant with the least amount of interests

So what I've done so far is create 2 classes, the Participant and Interest, where the Interest is Hashable so that I can create a Set with it. I manually created 8 participants with different names and interests.

I've made an array of participants selected and I've used a basic for in loop to somewhat pair them together using the intersection() function of sets. Somehow my index always kicks out of range and I'm positive there's a better way of doing this, but it's just so messy and I don't know where to start.

```
for i in 0..<participantsSelected.count {
    if participantsSelected[i].interest.intersection(participantsSelected[i+1].interest) == [] {
        participantsSelected.remove(at: i)
        participantsSelected.remove(at: i+1)
        print (participantsSelected.count)
    }
}
```

So my other issue is using a for loop for this specific algorithm seems a bit off too since what if they all have 1 similar interest, and it won't equal to [] / nil.

Basically the output I'm trying is to remove them from the participants selected array once they're paired up, and for them to be paired up they would have to be with another participant with the least amount of interests with each other.

EDIT: Updated code, here's my attempt to improve my algorithm logic

```
for participant in 0..<participantsSelected {
    var maxInterestIndex = 10
    var currentIndex = 1
    for _ in 0..<participantsSelected {
        print (participant)
        print (currentIndex)
        let score = participantsAvailable[participant].interest.intersection(participantsAvailable[currentIndex].interest)
        print ("testing score, \(score.count)")
        if score.count < maxInterestIndex {
            maxInterestIndex = score.count
            print ("test, \(maxInterestIndex)")
        } else {
            pairsCreated.append(participantsAvailable[participant])
            pairsCreated.append(participantsAvailable[currentIndex])
            break
//            participantsAvailable.remove(at: participant)
//            participantsAvailable.remove(at: pairing)
        }
        currentIndex = currentIndex + 1
    }
}

for i in 0..<pairsCreated.count {
    print (pairsCreated[i].name)
}
```

Comment: Changing the size of the array while iterating through its indices is never going to end well

Comment: "Pair them with another participant with the least amount of interests". You mean pair them with least amount of common interests? Like if person A has interests X, Y and Z but person B has interests V, W, U this is a perfect match?

Comment: Yes, perhaps you could add an example to your question of the desired outputs for some inputs.

Comment: Yes, you are right Matic Oblak. Person A and Person B would match at that instance, instead of Person A and Person C who has interests F, X, G.

I didn't think of it that way Paulw11, you're right, that will mess up the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in the case that what you are looking for is to pair your participants (all of them) optimally regarding your criteria:
Then the way to go is by finding a perfect matching in a participants graph.
Create a graph with `n` vertices, `n` being the number of participants. We can denote by `u_p` the vertex corresponding to participant `p`.
Then, create weighted edges as follows:
For each couple of participants `p, q` (p != q), create the edge `(u_p, u_q)`, and weight it with the number of interests these two participants have in common.
Then, run a minimum weight perfect matching algorithm on your graph, and the job is done. You will obtain an optimal result (meaning the best possible, or one among the best possible matchings) in polynomial time.

Minimum weight perfect matching algorithm: The problem is strictly equivalent to the maximum weight matching algorithm. Find the edge of maximum weight (let's denote by `C` its weight). Then replace the weight `w` of each edge by `C-w`, and run a maximum weight matching algorithm on the resulting graph.

I would suggest that yoy use [Edmond's blossom algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) to find a perfect matching in your graph. First because it is efficient and well documented, second because I believe you can find implementations in most existing languages, but also because it truly is a very, very beautiful algorithm (it ain't called blossom for nothing).

Another possibility, if you are sure that your number of participants will be small (you mention 8), you can also go for a brute-force algorithm, meaning to test all possible ways to pair participants.
Then the algorithm would look like:

```
find_best_matching(participants, interests, pairs):
    if all participants have been paired:
        return sum(cost(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in pairs), pairs  // cost(p1, p2) = number of interests in common
    else:
        p = some participant which is not paired yet
        best_sum = + infinite
        best_pairs = empty_set
        for all participants q which have not been paired, q != p:
            add (p, q) to pairs
            current_sum, current_pairs = find_best_matching(participants, interests, pairs)
            if current_sum < best_sum:
                best_sum = current_sum
                best_pairs = current_pairs
            remove (p, q) from pairs
        return best_sum, best_pairs
```

Call it initially with `find_best_matching(participants, interests, empty_set_of_pairs)` to get the best way to match your participants.

Comment: I'm still unsure about what all this means, I'm sorry I'm a beginner, is there a way to explain this in easier terms?

Comment: Which specific part(s) are you not getting ? I can edit the post and develop a bit if you tell me. But if you're a beginner in algorithmic, then the blossom algorithm is going to be a real heel to implement, so I'd advice you to go for a brute force approach.

Comment: Hi, I've attempted to improve my code, if you could check out my edit so far that would be great! Thank you so much for responding again

Comment: Your code is still not a recursive function. As you can see in the algorithm I wrote, it is a recursive function (a function which calls itself). Try to understand of it works, and to read about recursion as it is a very important programming concept.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your code too.. I'm sorry I'm still learning

Comment: I think I'm getting the hang of it, my issue now is that when I remove p and q from the Array of Participants, it doesn't let me as the array is a parameter which is a constant, what do you think I'm doing wrong?